How can I extend this object so that I can programmatically set the center of view in addition to the zoom level?
I extended another user's posted solution for this ZoomableContainer to enable a pinch and scroll for my SwiftUI App. I'm able to programmatically set the zoom level, but can't figure out the coordinates for the drag to scroll behavior so that I can modify them externally, like a bookmark for a specific zoom level centered on a particular coordinate within the container. Would love any pointers on a good way to do this, especially one that is bindable to other views for flexibility.
struct ZoomableContainer<Content: View>: View {

    let content: Content

    @Binding private var currentScale: CGFloat
    @State private var tapLocation: CGPoint = .zero
    @Binding var maxAllowedScale: CGFloat
    @Binding var mapViewCenter: CGPoint?
    @Binding var mapViewZoom: CGFloat?

    init(currentScale: Binding<CGFloat>, maxAllowedScale: Binding<CGFloat>, mapViewCenter: Binding<CGPoint?>, mapViewZoom: Binding<CGFloat?>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        print ("ZoomableContainer Init")
        _currentScale = currentScale
        self.content = content()
        _maxAllowedScale = maxAllowedScale
        _mapViewCenter = mapViewCenter
        _mapViewZoom = mapViewZoom
    }

    func setCurrentCenterAndZoom(center: CGPoint, zoom: CGFloat) {
        mapViewCenter = center
        mapViewZoom = zoom
    }

    func doubleTapAction(location: CGPoint) {
        tapLocation = location
        currentScale = currentScale == 1.0 ? maxAllowedScale : 1.0
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZoomableScrollView(scale: $currentScale, tapLocation: $tapLocation, maxScale: maxAllowedScale, mapViewCenter: $mapViewCenter, mapViewZoom: $mapViewZoom) {
            content
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: doubleTapAction)
    }

    fileprivate struct ZoomableScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
        private var content: Content
        @Binding private var currentScale: CGFloat
        @Binding private var tapLocation: CGPoint
        private let maxScale: CGFloat
        @Binding var mapViewCenter: CGPoint?
        @Binding var mapViewZoom: CGFloat?

        init(scale: Binding<CGFloat>, tapLocation: Binding<CGPoint>, maxScale: CGFloat, mapViewCenter: Binding<CGPoint?>, mapViewZoom: Binding<CGFloat?>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
            _currentScale = scale
            _tapLocation = tapLocation
            self.maxScale = maxScale
            _mapViewCenter = mapViewCenter
            _mapViewZoom = mapViewZoom
            self.content = content()
        }

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
            let scrollView = UIScrollView()
            scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = maxScale
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
            scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            scrollView.clipsToBounds = false

            let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
            hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
            scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)

            return scrollView
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: content), scale: $currentScale)
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
            print ("running updateUIView")
            context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = content

            if uiView.zoomScale > uiView.minimumZoomScale {
                uiView.setZoomScale(currentScale, animated: true)
                mapViewZoom = currentScale
                print ("setting Zoom Scale")
            } else if tapLocation != .zero {
                uiView.zoom(to: zoomRect(for: uiView, scale: uiView.maximumZoomScale, center: tapLocation), animated: true)
                mapViewCenter?.x = tapLocation.x
                mapViewCenter?.y = tapLocation.y
                mapViewZoom = currentScale
                DispatchQueue.main.async { tapLocation = .zero }
                print("tapLocation")
            } else if let center = mapViewCenter, let zoom = mapViewZoom {
                uiView.zoom(to: zoomRect(for: uiView, scale: zoom, center: center), animated: true)
                print ("coords and zoom")
            }

            assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
        }

        func zoomRect(for scrollView: UIScrollView, scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
            print ("Running zoomRect")
            let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
            let width = scrollViewSize.width / scale
            let height = scrollViewSize.height / scale
            let x = center.x - (width / 2.0)
            let y = center.y - (height / 2.0)

            return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        }

        class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
            var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
            @Binding var currentScale: CGFloat

            init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>, scale: Binding<CGFloat>) {
                self.hostingController = hostingController
                _currentScale = scale
            }

            func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
                return hostingController.view
            }

            func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
                currentScale = scale
            }
        }
    }
}

I've added various print statements to see where this code executes when I drag to scroll around my map, but haven't figured out a place to extract coordinates from.
